# Distribution of sums of random variables over finite field

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, finite-fields

Let $q$ be an odd prime, $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables over $\mathbb Z_q$, and $0 < p < 1$ be some constant.  Let $X_i$ take on the value $0$ with probability $p$, and the remaining probability mass be distributed uniformly among the other $q - 1$ values, i.e.
$$
\begin{align*}
\Pr[X_i = 0] &= p \\
\Pr[X_i = j] &= \frac{1 - p}{q - 1}\text{ for }j \ne 0\text{.}
\end{align*}
$$
What can one say about the distribution of $\sum\nolimits_{i = 1}^{n} X_i \pmod q$?

I tried doing things inductively, but couldn't arrive at a pattern.

I can tell that there are $q + 1$ ways to obtain each number $k \in \mathbb Z_q$ in $X_1 + X_2$, so it shouldn't be too hard to argue that $\Pr[X_i = j]\text{ for }j \ne 0$ remains distributed uniformly among some probability mass, but what probability mass exactly gets left for them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can first solve the easier problem of finding the probability $p_k$ that $k$ uniformly random non-zero elements of $\mathbb Z_q$ add up to $0$. This probability satisfies the recurrence

$$
p_{k+1}=\frac1{q-1}(1-p_k)
$$

with the initial value $p_0=1$, with solution

$$
p_k=\frac{1-(1-q)^{1-k}}q\;.
$$

You're adding $k$ non-zero elements with probability $\binom nk(1-p)^kp^{n-k}$, so the total probability to get $0$ is

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(1-p)^kp^{n-k}\cdot\frac{1-(1-q)^{1-k}}q
&=
\frac1q\left(1-(1-q)^{1-n}(1-p+p(1-q))^n\right)
\\
&=
\frac1q\left(1+(q-1)\left(\frac{pq-1}{q-1}\right)^n\right)\;,
\end{align}

and the remaining probability is distributed uniformly among the non-zero elements.

Alternatively, you could directly [solve the recurrence](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a(n%2B1)%20%3D%20p%20*%20a(n)%20%2B%20(1-p)%20*%20(1%20-%20a(n))%20%2F%20(q%20-%201)&dataset=)

$$
a_{n+1}=pa_n+\frac{1-p}{q-1}(1-a_n)\;,
$$

which tracks the probability $a_n$ of having a zero sum after $n$ summands: With probability $p$ a zero summand is added to a zero sum, and with probability $\frac{1-p}{q-1}$ the right non-zero summand is added to a non-zero sum to make it zero.

Comment: How do you know that the remaining probability is distributed uniformly?  I'm sure it is true, but I don't think this is immediate.

Comment: @Batominovski: One can see combinatorially that for any nonzero $j$ the ways to obtain a sum of $j$ have the same structure.  Since things start out uniformly, they also remain that way.

Comment: @Batominovski: In other words, you can prove it by induction. If the sum is zero, every non-zero summand has the same probability, and if it's non-zero with uniform probability, every non-zero value can be reached from every other non-zero value in exactly one way. Alternatively, you could argue that the distribution must be invariant under permuting the non-zero elements by multiplication with some element other than $0$ or $1$.